# Do "superfast" keyed hash functions exist?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, performance, universal-hash

A common family of requirements for (cryptographic) keyed hash functions is that the function $h(k,-)$ should have good collision resistance for all keys $k$, even if the key $k$ is known to the attacker. I'm looking for something with slightly weaker security properties to this, but which is unusually fast. Specifically, I only need collision resistance subject to the assumption that $k$ is unknown to the attacker and kept secret. However, the task of computing $h(k, x)$ should be a lot faster than computing $\mathrm{Blake3}(k+x),$ where $k$ denotes concatenation, despite that $\mathrm{Blake3}$ is usually considered a "fast" hashing algorithm.

**Motivation:** The point is to get hashing speeds that are so high, that there's simply no reason not to hash an object before sending it to disk (e.g. if we're trying to free up RAM). This can easily be achieved using a non-cryptographic hash, of course, but hashes are more useful if they can be used to decide object equality without ever having to reload those objects from disk.

**Remark**: In case anyone's wondering, my personal interest in this topic stems from the problem of designing a virtual machine for a programming language I'm working on. Most uses probably won't be very IO intensive, but I'm designing things defensively to help ensure that things "just work" when the programmer starts doing funky things. For example, currently I've got timestamps attached to all objects, and depending on current RAM usage and the object's time-since-last-access, a memory management thread will sometimes decide to send the object to disk.

Anyway, a potential improvement on this design involves holding onto a small "avatar" for the object even after it's been dumped to disk. The avatar is supposed to track basic info about the object like its class, its reference count, as well as class-specific attributes of interest. For example, if it's a hashtable, the avatar might record the number of key-value pairs in the table. If it's a string, the avatar might record the length of the string, and possibly a bit more data to facilitate lazy deletion of characters from each end of the string. Wherever possible, you obviously try to do things via the avatar, without having to reload the entire object.

Of course, once this idea of avatars got into my head, the question of whether these avatars should store hashes of the objects they represent arose naturally. Computing them has a couple of benefits. For starters, it means that equality of objects can be checked via avatars, which is obviously quite appealing. It also allows you to avoid storing duplicate objects into the database.

On the other hand, I'm a bit worried about the runtime costs of computing these things. If someone's program literally never makes use of the hashes, that's a lot of CPU time consumed on something that isn't helping the end-user. I'd just feel a lot more comfortable with a computationally cheaper solution, and I think using a full-blown cryptographic hash like Blake3 might be overkill.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. We want cryptographic has functions (keyed or not) as fast as possible and as much as secure. We want slow hash functions ( well adjustable ) for the password hashing algorithm. maybe you just need https://xxhash.com/ also see at https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash

Comment: @kelalaka, well xxhash seems not to have the cryptographic properties I'm looking for, unfortunately.

Comment: What comes closest to your requirements are universal hashes; built with polynomial evaluation (GCM, Poly1305), or Cryptographic CRCs. The major drawback is that: most of the time, the adversary shouldn't learn the output of the hash. So you'd need to either pass this output through as a slower PRF or "encrypt" This output with a stream cipher.  Which may yield acceptable performance depending on your use. Caveat: these are usually quite brittle and misuses can be more devastating compared to regular hashing.

Comment: @MarcIlunga, okay, thanks. Cryptographic CRC's seem intriguing (in fact it would never have occurred to me that this was even possible).

Comment: @MarcIlunga universal hashes GCM and Poly1305 require a new key per hash. So, to compare two files one needs the same key which means the loss of the key. I don't see the reason for cryptographic hashes here, though.

Comment: @kelalaka, universal hashes need not changing keys . Only Poly1305 does, since it’s built an one time Mac. GCM doesn’t. See also the UHF-PRF composition of Shoup. In the end it depends what the goal is.

Comment: @MarcIlunga you are right about GCM, that I've confused the usage with AES-GCM where the key x-ored in the final part.

Comment: Yeah I'm noticing that a lot of these protocols demand that each message use its own special nonce. For the sake of equality testing, this is exactly what we *don't* want!

Comment: @MarcIlunga, what's an example of a cryptographic CRC?

Comment: @kodlu See "LFSR-based Hashing and Authentication" (1994)

Comment: @SocraticMathTutor unique nonces aren't a necessary requirement. You can compose the UHF with a PRF like siphash, the prodecure is fully deterministic on the key and input. That said, this doesn't mean I recommend doing any of that. As we've been discussing there a a few pitfalls to different approaches with UHFs. Also back to the motivation, your application seems IO intensive, are you really in a context where hashing is going to be the bottleneck? Unless you are working with special storage, blake3 is going to be fast enough for disk storage.

Comment: @MarcIlunga Okay, thanks for the info about the nonessentialness of nonces. I've responded to your query in the body of the question. Blake3 might be OK, but I'm also a bit worried about imposing the computational costs of Blake3 upon developers who might not ending up using these hashes at all. That's the main reason why I'm asking.

Comment: @MarcIlunga how do you use GCm without a key as the OPs requirement.

Comment: @kelalaka I wouldn't know how to use a keyless GCM for this task. But I understand OP is actually OK using keyed primitives. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @MarcIlunga GCM uses a key in the end, however, since the key is used again and the messages are there, then the key will be lost,